# $push is not supported in mongoose bulk operation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am using the bulk operation in mongoose to update multiple documents in a concurrent manner.

The update data looks as below:

```
let docUpdates = [
    {
        id : docId1,
        status : "created",
        $push : {
            updates : {
                status: "created",
                referenceId : referenceId,
                createdTimestamp : "2022-06-14T00:00:00.000Z"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        id : docId2,
        status : "completed",
        $push : {
            updates : {
                status: "compelted",
                referenceId : referenceId,
                createdTimestamp : "2022-06-14T00:00:00.000Z"
            }
        }
    },
];

// Update documents using bulk operation
let bulkUpdate = Model.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();

for (let i = 0; i < docUpdates.length; i++) {
    bulkUpdate.find({_id : docUpdates[i].docId}).updateOne({ $set : docUpdates[i]})
}
```

When I execute the above snippet, I get the below error.

```
(node:468) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoBulkWriteError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$push' in '$push' is not allowed in the context of an update's replacement document. Consider using an aggregation pipeline with $replaceWith.
    at OrderedBulkOperation.handleWriteError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/common.js:884:22)
```

Could you please help in finding a work around for this error.

Thank you,
KK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't that `$push` isn't supported, it's that the way you pass the arguments in the update document, it's interpreted as a top-level field. See the documentation about [field name considerations](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/dot-dollar-considerations/#std-label-crud-concepts-dot-dollar-considerations), specifically the section on [document modifying updates](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/dot-dollar-considerations/#document-modifying-updates).

This section of your code `updateOne({ $set : docUpdates[i]})` is equivalent to the following:

```
updateOne({
  $set: {
    id: docId1,
    status: "created",
    $push: {
      updates: {
        status: "created",
        referenceId: referenceId,
        createdTimestamp: "2022-06-14T00:00:00.000Z"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Because the `$push` is contained in the `$set`, you're telling MongoDB to set the value of a field named `$push` to a document with a field called `updates`, which has `status`, `referenceId`, and `createdTimestamp` fields.

What you want to do instead, is specify an update document with two different update operators. In other words, `$push` needs to be on the same level as the `$set`.

Something like:

```
updateOne({
  $set: {
    id: docId1,
    status: "created"
  },
  $push: {
    updates: {
      status: "created",
      referenceId: referenceId,
      createdTimestamp: "2022-06-14T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
  }
})
```

How you represent that in the `docUpdates` array is up to you. Maybe you can do something like:

```
let docUpdates = [
    {
        id : docId1,
        update : {
            $set : {
               status : "created"
            },
            $push : {
                updates : {
                    status: "created",
                    referenceId : referenceId,
                    createdTimestamp : "2022-06-14T00:00:00.000Z"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // ... Other updates
]
```

And use it in the loop like:

```
bulkUpdate.find({_id : docUpdates[i].docId}).updateOne(docUpdates[i].update)
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me the mistake in my approach, I have updated the code as per your suggestions and now it seems to be working fine. However regarding the sub-document `updates` is missing an parameter `_id` when I update using bulk operation. any thoughts on this please?

Comment: `_id` is immutable, meaning it cannot be changed. In case you do have a different field, `id`, in what circumstances would you want to change it?

Comment: For `updates` sub-document it usually creates `_id` by default whenever I push an object. However in my case it did not generate the Id. If I use `Date.now()` to save the timestamp, it is saving as unix timestamp instead of ISO Date.

Comment: I see. Feel free to update the logic to suit your use case. `Date.now()` will always return a timestamp, you can look into using [`toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString).

Comment: Thank you, Apparently conversion creates the timestamp in this format `'2022-06-14T08:18:23.331Z'`, but usually it is saved in `ISODate("2022-06-14T08:17:51.874Z")` format.